# Xcode 8 with older editor font

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode8

Xcode 8 has brought some new kind of editor font. I don't like this font, how to return the font of IDE to Xcode 7 like editor font?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences and than select font you want:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. Am I right that font has been changed? I opened the preferences window and just selected other theme option then selected back the default, then font name "SF Mono Regular" appeard in the box, then i closed that window i am not sure if it is the old font or still the new. It looks better now, but maybe it is only illusion. It reminds me the old funny accident when one pc admin set Firefox as default browser to user who was familiar with IE but this user noticed that and was complaining. So the administrator changed the icon of Firefox app to IE icon and user was happy again :))